# Need help making prime numbers row in {c}

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

I need to make a program in {c} that  would give me prime number for entered number (example is user enter 50. to write back 229)
So, I am stuck when making loop. 
I am tring to define for row[100] to have row[0]=2,row[1]=3 and then I make i=4 and try to make a loop that would for number i devide number i with every single number in the row (becose those I know are prime numbers) and get module (number after 0,not sure how it is said on english), and then if if all of them have module !=0 then I know it is prime number and I want to add it into row.

So is there a way somebody can help me write this line? Thanks alot in advance  :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int i,numb=4,position,temp,temp1,row[100];
  printf(" enter position (1-100)\n");
  scanf("%d",&position);
  if (position>100||position<0 )
  {
       printf("error,enter position between 1 and 100"); 
       return(0);
   }
   row[0]=2;
   row[1]=3;
   i=2;
   do
   {
          temp=numb%2;                       
          temp1=numb%3;
          if (temp!=0 && temp1!=0)
          {
              row[i]=numb;
             i++;
           }
          numb++;
      }
      while (i<100);
      printf("%d. prime number is %d",position,row[position]);
      return 0;
}
```

Ok,so I need to change part where I ask for module from deviding wit 2 and 3 to asking for module from deviding from all numbers in row at that moment. Thank you for help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no coding service. Show your code and tell us where your **specific** problem is.

Comment: Or just type `[c] prime` into that little box in the upper right corner.

Comment: @Olaf I added code,can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_N 100

int main(void){
    int i, odd, temp, position, n = 0, row[MAX_N];

    row[n++]=2;
    row[n++]=3;
    for(odd = 5; n < MAX_N; odd += 2){
        int is_prime = 1;//true
        for(i = 1; i < n; ++i){
            temp = row[i];
            if(temp * temp > odd)
                break;
            if(odd % temp == 0){
                is_prime = 0;//false
                break;
            }
        }
        if(is_prime)
            row[n++] = odd;
    }

    printf(" enter position (1-%d)\n", MAX_N);
    scanf("%d", &position);
    if (position > 100 || position < 1){
        printf("error,enter position between 1 and %d\n", MAX_N); 
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d. prime number is %d", position, row[position - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```